# What is the movie playing on TV on Logan and what is its connection to the film?

Tags: analysis, x-men-cinematic-universe, reference, logan

In [Logan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3315342/?ref_=nv_sr_1), a movie is shown on TV. It is an old western, nearly 80 years old. They quote some lines of the movie, something like:

> Now you run on home to your mother, and tell her... tell her everything's all right. And there aren't any guns in the valley.

### What movie is this and what is its connection to *Logan*?

Comment: there's an article about how Patrick stewart saw this movie in theatres (I think, maybe I made it up cause I can't find it)

Comment: or maybe that was in the movie and I'm getting my signals crossed...

Comment: Both, per IMDB:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3315342/trivia?item=tr3308395

Comment: The _entire_ movie's philosophy is inspired by _Shane_ (1953). Wisecrack did [an entire video analysing Logan's philosophy and it's amazing](https://youtu.be/tHLw7ox458c)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's 1953's western film [Shane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shane_(film)).

Confirmed on [thrillist.com](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/logan-movie-shane-reference-classic-western-film) too

And the full dialogue was:

> **Shane:** I gotta be going one.
>
> **Joey:** Why, Shane?
>
> **Shane:** A man has to be what he is, Joey. Can't break the mould. I tried it and it didn't work for me.
>
> **Joey:** We want you, Shane.
>
> **Shane:** Joey, there's no living with... with a killing. There's no going back from one. Right or wrong, it's a brand. A brand sticks. There's no going back. Now you run on home to your mother, and tell her... tell her everything's all right. And there aren't any guns in the valley.

Source: [geekendgladiators.com](https://geekendgladiators.com/2017/03/06/what-was-that-western-movie-in-logan/)

And here is video for that specific scene:

From [usatoday.com](http://www.usatoday.com/story/life/movies/2017/03/01/hugh-jackman-logan-influences/98535442/)

> Mangold mentioned the 1953 Western Shane, the story of a tired gunfighter (Alan Ladd) who falls in with a boy and his family. That movie would influence the core relationship between Logan and Laura, who are both distrustful of the other but find common ground.
>
> And if it was Jackman’s goodbye to Logan, Mangold thought it should definitely explore the hero’s biggest fear: “Is he frightened of villains? No. Aliens? No. Galactic destruction? No. His own demise? No. But he is scared of love.”

Even Mangold has a personal liking for the film, which is clear from [his old tweet](https://twitter.com/mang0ld/status/307962898288873472).

[image]

Comment: The Negotiator has some commentary about Shane that seems relevant:  "I like westerns, like Shane." "It's interesting that you pick one where the hero dies." "What are you talking about? **He doesn't die.**"  "That's a common misconception, in the last frame he's slumped over on his horse." "So he was slumped, **slumped don't mean dead**."  With Logan and his abilities, it's entirely possible that "buried six feet under" doesn't mean dead either.

Answer (score 7):

As others have answered, the movie in question is "Shane".

I believe one connection to the film is that in a lot of ways, "Logan" is more of a western than a superhero film.  It has many of the standard elements you saw in an old western, such as revenge, redemption, protection of innocents against an invading force. Logan doesn't want to be a violent man but is forced to by his circumstances.  He is basically the "nameless hero" of the classic western.  Heck, toss out the adamantium and set back the clock 200 years, and it IS a western.  Adding the clip from "Shane" was the director wink-and-a-smile acknowledging this.

Comment: I even liked the idea of the X-men comics in the film being analogous to the 19th century dime novels based on actual people and events.